# Gnu Plot - ';' expected - error

Tags: loops, gnuplot

I have a set of *.txt files, called test0001.txt, test0002.txt, .....
I want to convert the data of these files to *.png images (Out0001.png, ...).

```
set xrange [0:50]
set yrange [0:50]
set size square
set nokey
set pointsize 0.5
set terminal png size 1024,1024
do for [t=1:50] {
    outfile = sprintf('Out%04.0f.png',t)
    set output outfile
    plot ('test%04.0f.txt',t) using 1:2 with points pt 7 lc rgb "black"
}
```

I get "';' expected in line 12" as error. Just typing in the *.txt file names works btw:

```
    plot 'test0001.txt' using 1:2 with points pt 7 lc rgb "black"
```

This just creates the first image 50 times.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I'd be looking at was this line:

```
plot ('test%04.0f.txt',t) using 1:2 with points pt 7 lc rgb "black"
```

Since an earlier line used `sprintf` to do this string formatting, shouldn't you be looking at something like:

```
plot sprintf('test%04.0f.txt',t) using 1:2 with points pt 7 lc rgb "black"
```

Or, in toto, something like:

```
set xrange [0:50]
set yrange [0:50]
set size square
set nokey
set pointsize 0.5
set terminal png size 1024,1024
do for [t=1:50] {
    inpfile = sprintf('Out%04.0f.txt',t)
    outfile = sprintf('Out%04.0f.png',t)
    set output outfile
    plot inpfile using 1:2 with points pt 7 lc rgb "black"
}
```